# Google drive backup failed

Tags: backup, google-drive

Failed with an unknown error.

Getting this while try to back up my files on ubuntu. I tried sudo nano /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/globals.py^C
and changed run time from 30 to 200. But still getting failed with an unknown error

---

Thanks for your reply. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with deja-dup version 40.7. I tried backing up through the terminal via deja-dup. It gives error as follows:
[image: error]

Comment: You have not really given much information, what version of Ubuntu? what version of deja-dup? `deja-dup --version`. How are you running backup, via command line or GUI? How are you connecting to Google Drive? Can you open & copy files manually to/from Google drive? If you do this on the command line before running `deja-dup` it should output a load of debug info which may give more info about the error: `export DEJA_DUP_DEBUG=1`